# Policy on tech support questions related to games

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

I noticed the question [i3 core performance problems](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/9893/i3-core-performance-problems) migrated from Superuser to Gaming. It is essentially a tech support question about Linux graphics driver problems/performance.

I personally think this question is off-topic on Gaming SE, but there are probably more ambiguous questions about technical problems with games that may have a place here.

What is the policy on technical questions related to gaming? Are they excluded completely, or do they belong here on Gaming SE in some cases?

Comment: [First policy](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/253/hardware-questions), [about setup](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/307/are-questions-about-setting-up-consoles-pcs-on-topic), [also about setup](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/692/do-we-allow-questions-about-how-to-set-up-a-computer-for-certain-games), and [some warnings about our ability to handle tech support](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/1173/are-questions-about-games-that-wont-start-wanted-here).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The general policy is that yes, they do belong, so long as the question is specific to either gaming hardware, software, or peripherals, or otherwise unanswerable outside the context of 'Gaming'.

(I.E., more generalized Windows questions, even if you only use your Windows PC for games, would be off topic.)